# CORS error even after setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin or other Access-Control-Allow-* headers on client side

Tags: webpack, cors, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-resource

I have a Vue application generated with `webpack-simple` option. I am trying to make a `GET` request to `https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en` but I get the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   `https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en`.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '`http://127.0.0.1:8080`' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I am using vue-resource and have added:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
```

That has no effect.

I also added this in the `devServer` option in the `webpack.config.js`:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  noInfo: true,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
}
```

That isn't solving the problem either; the error message remains the same.

How to go about solving this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a *response* header the responding server must send.

And all other `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers are response headers for servers to send.

If you don’t control the server your request is sent to, and the problem with the response is just the lack of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header or other `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers you can still get things to work—by making the request through a CORS proxy.

You can easily run your own proxy using code from https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/.
You can also easily deploy your own proxy to Heroku in just 2-3 minutes, with 5 commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere.git
cd cors-anywhere/
npm install
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

After running those commands, you’ll end up with your own CORS Anywhere server running at, e.g., `https://cryptic-headland-94862.herokuapp.com/`.

Now, prefix your request URL with the URL for your proxy:

```
https://cryptic-headland-94862.herokuapp.com/https://example.com
```

Adding the proxy URL as a prefix causes the request to get made through your proxy, which:

1. Forwards the request to `https://example.com`.
2. Receives the response from `https://example.com`.
3. Adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response.
4. Passes that response, with that added header, back to the requesting frontend code.

The browser then allows the frontend code to access the response, because that response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what the browser sees.

This works even if the request is one that triggers browsers to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request, because in that case, the proxy also sends back the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers needed to make the preflight successful.

And if you have frontend code that adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header or other `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers to the request, remove that code — because the only effect you have by adding those request headers is, you’re triggering your browser to send [a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) rather than the actual `GET` or `POST` request in your code.

Comment: I'd note that `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` is a decent *temporary* solution, but not one you'll want to be using in production, as it may involve passing sensitive data through someone else's app.

Comment: @ceejayoz True but in this case the request is a simple GET without credentials, being made to what seems to be a publicly-available service that sends back random quotes. So in the case, the proxy is just a way to get around the fact the providers of that service aren’t bothering to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to responses themselves. There doesn’t seem to be any good reason they couldn’t be…

Answer (score -1):

For running the web app on your local system, you can disable the Chrome security feature by adding --disable-web-security flag.

I used the following commands on Windows to resolve XMLHttpError:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application & chrome.exe "http://localhost:8000/" --user-data-dir="C:\new" --disable-web-security
cd C:\flutter\MyProject\build\web & python -m http.server 8000
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, this answer is not really related to the question but it can be useful for those, who can't touch API server side, use free to use proxy [service from Rob--W](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere)

```
function doCORSRequest(appUrl) {
  const cors_api_url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
  let nUrl = cors_api_url + appUrl;

  fetch(nUrl)
    .then(response => {
      if(response.status !== 200) {
        alert("Error :( try later.")
        return;
      }
      response.json()
        .then(data => showResult(data))
    })
}

doCORSRequest(yourURL);
```