# How do I set CORS headers in vuejs2?

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I am using `axios` a get method. I also have set `CORS` header, but it keeps giving me error saying `Cross-Origin Request Blocked`.

Vue.js2:

```
methods: {
    getSliderData () {
      axios
        .get('/sliders', {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'Application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
          }
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
  }
```

Error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/sliders. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header.

Comment: Where should I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?

Comment: On the server https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Adding this header or similar CORS headers on the client side (Ajax) has no positive effect on CORS errors. You need to enable CORS on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS error even after setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232370/cors-error-even-after-setting-access-control-allow-origin-on-client-side)

Comment: CORS headers are been send from server side and then client(browser) according to it to determine reject response or not or do something else