# CORS error on AXIOS post to Pardot endpoint

Tags: axios, cors, pardot

I'm trying to post to a Pardot form handler endpoint using Nuxt/Axios.  It's getting blocked on the prefetch check.  Any thoughts on how to get around this?

```
const url = 'https://[pardot-endpoint]';
        const requestBody = {
          'Form Data': 'example',
        }
 const config = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          }
        }
 this.$axios.post(url, requestBody, config).then(response => {console.log(response)})
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://[endpoint]' from origin 'http://my.domain.local' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS error even after setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin or other Access-Control-Allow-\* headers on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232370/cors-error-even-after-setting-access-control-allow-origin-or-other-access-contro)

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're having this error is because the **server** you are trying to reach doesn't have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

To fix this problem you either make the fetch from the same origin as the server or you add the missing header on your **response headers**, specifying the origin or using the wildcard `*` (but this is not encouraged as you're allowing any origin to access resources from the server).

You can read more on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: I have access-control-allow-orgin with '*' in my header

Comment: Yes, but that header must go in the **response headers**, on the server configuration. The header you are setting is in the **request headers**, on the client side.

Comment: Gotcha, unfortunately since it's Pardot, I don't have the ability to change that header.