# Flutter Web requests using http package failing due to CORS

Tags: dart, http, cors, flutter-web

#### Background

I am using [GitHub Codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces), which does port forwarding for locally-hosted applications. So when I run `flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname 127.0.0. --web-port` the localhost URL is mirrored with a `githubpreview.dev` URL.

On the client side, I have a function to test the connection with the database:

```dart
static Future<bool> testConnection() async {
    http.Response response = await _httpClient.get(
      Uri.parse(baseUrl + 'test'), // requestObject.slug.string
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer 69',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
            "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,locale",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
      },
    );
```

`_httpClient` is a wrapper over `HttpClient()`.
On the server side, I have the function as follows:

```js
export function use_test(request) {
    console.log(`test request:${request.headers.origin}`);
    let options = {
        "headers":{
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
                "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,locale",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":
                "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
          },
        "body": {
            "payload": {
                "msg": request['headers']
            }
        }
    };
    return ok(options);
}
```

#### Issue

Whenever `testConnection` is run, the request is sent successfully, since the server logs the incoming request, but the response sent by the server is not received by the client, failing with an `XMLHttpRequestError`. Now, I have come across this error many times when writing Flutter Web applications, but this one stumps me. [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) can receive the data all right, so I'm pretty sure [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is to blame for this issue.

#### Additional Information

Flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.1.0-0.0.pre.1354, on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 5.4.0-1074-azure, locale
    en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.1.0-0.0.pre.1354 on channel master at /workspaces/Lighthouse-Web/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision a30012b275 (3 days ago), 2022-06-22 17:04:07 -0700
    • Engine revision fc08bf45b0
    • Dart version 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-216.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.14.0

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✗] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    ✗ clang++ is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install clang), or can be downloaded from
      https://releases.llvm.org/
    ✗ CMake is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install cmake), or can be downloaded from
      https://cmake.org/download/
    ✗ ninja is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install ninja-build), or can be downloaded from
      https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases
    ✗ pkg-config is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install pkg-config), or can be downloaded from
      https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux • linux-x64 • Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 5.4.0-1074-azure

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232370/cors-error-even-after-setting-access-control-allow-origin-or-other-access-contro

Comment: I tried the methods suggested in both answers but they did not work. However, I would recommend those experience a similar issue to take a look at those answers. Also, I'm trying out WebSocket to see if it would be better for my app, and the problems seems to be with the setup anyway, so I'm going to close the question in the meantime. Thanks for the links though!

Comment: For those wondering how to solve *this* problem, I used `HttpRequest.requestCrossOrigin` from `dart:html` instead of `HttpClient` from the `http` package.

Comment: Don't hesitate to write (and then accept) your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those wondering how to solve this problem, I used `HttpRequest.requestCrossOrigin` from `dart:html` instead of `HttpClient` from the `http` package.

## Sample Code

Whenever a cross-origin request is blocked, it is typically because the response from the server does not have the right CORS permissions, and is blocked by the browser before reaching the client. To remedy this, we need to add in the following headers in our server code (`server.js` in my case):

```js
function options(origin) {
    return {
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": origin,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        },
        "body": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This generates, for each request to the server, a template response that enables the request's origin in the CORS permissions. This response can then be modified throughout the rest of the endpoint's code to add payload to the `body` and such.

Next, the endpoint in the server looks like this:

```js
export async function use_postTest(request) {
    // The body of the POST request, stored as a JSON object
    let reqBody = JSON.parse(await request.body.text());
    // Create the template response with the incoming origin
    let res = options(request.headers.origin);
    // Modifying the response data
    res.status = res.body.status.code = 200;
    res.body.status.msg = "All ok!";
    // Passing the incoming request body back to the client, to show that the POST request can be processed
    res.body.payload.push(reqBody);
    return response(res);
}
```

That aside, we now code the client. Take note that **this solution is only for Flutter Web apps, since it uses `dart:html`, a set of services only available for the web platform.**

Our `.dart` file has the following code to send POST requests with JSON bodies:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';

Future<void> postCrossOrigin() async {
  final HttpRequest request = await HttpRequest.request(
    "https://...",
    method: 'POST',
    // the Map has to be encoded using jsonEncode
    sendData: jsonEncode({
      'a': 1,
      'b': [2, 3, 4],
      'c': true,
    }),
  );
  // Alternatively, use jsonDecode(request.responseText) to convert the response to a native Map object
  print(request.responseText);
}
```

`flutter run -d chrome` to obtain the following result in the console:

```
{"status":{"code":200,"msg":"All ok!"},"payload":[{"a":1,"b":[2,3,4],"c":true}]}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you could add sample code please.

Comment: Sample please. My dear Senior ordered me to find a sample , otherwise i may not able to pay my rent this month   :(