# Flutter Web CORS error only when deployed

Tags: flutter, firebase, web, proxy, cors

I am building a flutter app that uses a GET request to Google Apps Script to fetch data. It is working completely fine on Android and web applications hostet on localhost. Initially, I got CORS errors on localhost as well, but I fixed it by using a CORS proxy (namely "https://thingproxy.freeboard.io"). It even runs when built in release mode. However, as soon as I deploy the applicaiton to firebase ("firebase deploy"), the CORS proxy is not working anymore and returns CORS errors. Is there any difference between the locally hostet web app in release mode and the one hosted on firebase regarding the CORS proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Solved according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44232651/10116480. However, why the thingyproxy is not working when deployed is still unclear.